# How to force the proper order with my javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I have this JavaScript/jQuery

```
$('.next').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var table = $('table.active');
  var form = table.find('form');
  form.submit();
  window.location.href = '/some/location';
});
```

The problem is that in some browsers `Safari` being one of them the `form.submit()` never gets called.

My guess is this is an **async** request and never gets a chance to do that call.

Any ideas on how to do this. I tried the following

```
  form.submit(function(){
     window.location.href = '/some/location';
  });
```

But that didnt work

Comment: You can't submit the form *and* go to a different URL.

Comment: Doing both of those things doesn't make sense. Either submit a form, or reload the page. Once you've done either, the browser is essentially free to ignore anything else you do.

Comment: strange that it only happens in some browsers.. is there any console output?

Comment: its an ajax submit with so yes I can

Comment: Not the way you coded it now

Comment: Why are you performing an ajax post at all? It doesn't really make much sense to prevent the default form post and then perform ajax, followed by a redirect when you could instead just post to the act page and have the act page redirect. It's one less request, one less set of http headers and cookies being sent. It's simpler. Less complex. Possibly easier to maintain.

Comment: I think the main point is that you are not actually creating any sort of AJAX request at all.  `form.submit()` simply submits the form synchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like

```
$(function() {
  $('.next').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var table = $('table.active');
    var form = table.find('form');
    $.post(form.attr("action"),function() {
      window.location.href = '/some/location';
    });
  });
});
```

with parameters try

```
    $.post(form.attr("action"),form.serializeArray(),function() {
```

Comment: probably strategic... no?

Comment: Possibly - that is even worse :< - Mark's suggestion was also commentlessly downvoted

Comment: Yeah, well your answer is good and implements automatic serialisation of the form inputs, so I'll vote this up.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do something via AJAX.

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $("#formID").submit(function(event) {

      /* stop form from submitting normally */
      event.preventDefault();

      /* get some values from elements on the page: */
      var $form = $( this ),
          term = $form.find( 'input[name="s"]' ).val(),
          url = $form.attr( 'action' );

      /* Send the data using post */
      var posting = $.post( url, { s: term } );

      /* Redirect the client */
      posting.done(function( data ) {
        window.location.href = '/some/location';
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

This will behave differently in different browsers that allow the submission of a form to be overridden if the window.location is allowed to interrupt that request.

If your intent to submit the contents of the form as ajax you need to collect your form fields into an object that can be then sent with ajax and in the ajax request you send that object to the server, and on success you redirect to the page you wish.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: stringifyedData
}).done(function ( data ) {
  window.location = "/some/location";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to do the redirect to `/some/location` on the page your form's `action` argument goes to.

Comment: @Trace no it's not, unless there's a "submit" handler you haven't posted.

Comment: You are trying to redirect before your AJAX call is comeplete. Put `doSomething()`  into the success / complete section of your ajax function.

Comment: The submit is calling a rails action that is using remote true which is using ajax behind the scene

Comment: @Trace then you need to do the window location in the success of that "behind the scene" ajax request. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to delay setting the `location.href`, so that the Ajax request gets sent by the browser first. You do not need to wait for a response:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = '/some/location';
}, 1);
```

Comment: You have no idea of how long you need to wait. Change location too soon and the submission is aborted. Since Ajax has a callback, that is the only place to put the location change

Comment: You don't have to wait at all. The Ajax request will always be sent before the window.location change, as long as the change is done asynchronously, because it comes first in the event loop.

Comment: I strongly doubt that, but have not tested it. It needs to be tested on a slow server or a server that takes a while to respond